# Andengine: FileNotFoundException: Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource

Tags: android, filesystems, andengine

I'm trying to load texture from mounted obb expansion file, but AndEngine can't open this file. That's my code:

```
    BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas atlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(textureManager, 2048, 2048, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath(obbManager.getMainRoot() + "/");
    File file = new File(obbManager.getMainRoot() + "/background.png");
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    background = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlas, this, "background.png");
```

And that's what I see in Logcat:

```
02-10 22:40:09.170: INFO/System.out(20962): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
02-10 22:40:09.180: ERROR/AndEngine(20962): Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: /mnt/obb/8d6d9efb8ab5fbfaa452d7ff7e8047c5/background.png
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/obb/8d6d9efb8ab5fbfaa452d7ff7e8047c5/background.png
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
        at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:48)
        at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:39)
        at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:140)
        at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:132)
        at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:128)
```

So, the file exists, but I'm still getting FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it: `createFromAsset` tried to find my file not in `/mnt/.../background.png`, but in apk's `assets/mnt/.../background.png`. So I should use AndEngine's FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource:

```
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(atlas, FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(file))
```

Comment: where to get the obbManager.getMainRoot() object from

Comment: @voidRy that's from my helper class that you can find [here](https://github.com/uncleLem/AndroidUtils/blob/master/src/ua/a5/androidutils/utils/ObbExpansionsManager.java). Feel free to use it!

Comment: Confirmed, you should make your directory as Project/.../assets/gfx/background.png and this means you should add a folder called gfx or something else, then, insert your file in it. It worked for me. Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this

```
background = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlas, getAssets(), "background.png");
```

instead of

```
background = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlas, this, "background.png");
```